# Finding the minimal polynomial of A with its Characteristic polynomial and dimensions of eigenspaces given.

Tags: linear-algebra, minimal-polynomials

Let $A$ be a $6\times 6$ complex matrix with Characteristic Polynomial, $c_A(x) = (x^2+1)^3$,
$\dim E(i) = 2$ and $\dim E(-i) = 1$. Find the minimal polynomial of $A$.

Comment: Welcome to math.stackexchange. Your experience will be improved if instead of simply posting your assigned problem (which you phrase as if you were assigning homework to the site, which you are certainly not doing), you include your thoughts or your attempts and what is causing you problems in trying to solve the problem. The site frowns on people who just post problems with no context, no information about what they’ve tried (or what they know), and no sign of having expended any effort in solving tghe problem themselves.

Comment: I am extremely sorry, I thought this site works in that way so i just posted it. Anyway I figured out a way to solve this problem, wanna make sure its correct....here from CP, we get the eigenvalues as i and -i, and the minimal polynomial would be (x-i)^2.(x+i), is this correct?

Comment: You can post your answer as an edit to your question, and ask for verificaiton. Add the tag `proof-verification`.